Why does my PC stay on after Windows shuts down?
I am using the MSI B350 PC-Mate with the following hardware:
CPU: Ryzen 7 5700x
Graphics Card: GeForce RTX 3060 12 GB
PSU: Be Quiet! Pure Power 11 700W
I am also using an AiO and a manually installed AX200 WiFi Card. I need to add that the following problem existed before installing the WiFi-Card.
My OS is Windows 11.
Ever since upgrading my CPU and GPU to the mentioned above, i have been facing power issues with that setup where the PC won't shut down.
After Windows shuts down successfully, the PC stays on, including the Motherboard, the cooling system and the Case Fans aswell as the Power-LED. The only way to shut it down is pushing the power button for a few seconds. After that, i can boot it up normally.
This doesn't happen all the time. It usually only happens after playing videogames.
What i have tried so far (unsuccessfully):

Clean install Windows 11
Disable Windows Fast Startup
Bios Update
Updating Chipset Drivers
Deleting video drivers with DDU, installing the latest video drivers (manually as well as via Windows Update)
Using another graphics card
Check the CPU temperatures before shutting down
Enable ErP Settings in BIOS
CLR CMOS
shutdown via shutdown /s /f /t

I am suspecting the Motherboard here because the last time i updated the BIOS, the PC showed the same behaviour a few times after entering M-Flash Mode.
I hope someone has an idea on how to solve this as this has been happening for about half a year now and i can't find a solution. Thanks in advance!

How long have you waited?

5-6 hours was the most i think

Try disabling hibernation via admin elevated command prompt powercfg /hibernate off and then see if it shuts down fully and properly as expected.

nope, doesn't help.

Try Shutdown command, one of:
shutdown.exe /s /t 0
shutdown.exe -s -t 0
shutdown.exe /s /t 0 /f

or from PowerShell
Stop-Computer -Force

what's the result?

I've tried shutdown /s /f /t 5 and it didn't work. Is there a chance that shutdown.exe /s /t 0 would work? Thanks

By "didn't work" I mean that the PC shows the same behaviour after shutting windows down as by using the shutdown button. :)

what is the name of the videogame? it may be necessary to force close all related processes via the task manager.  check it using tasklist.exe | find.exe /i "name of game" or tasklist.exe
